# Connection of php and mysql database with android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to connect database in MySQL with android,but when data enter in NewProductActivity and click on createproduct button then generate error of Unfortunately has stopped. code given below. In this database path is given but i don't know exactly which path i have to give because i used wamp and database open through localhost. After running this program, click on button to insert value in database pointer go into createProduct class and its method but do not go into doInbackground().

```
//NewProductActivity
package com.example.projectewithmysql;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity 
{
    private EditText inputName;
    private EditText inputPrice;
    private EditText inputDesc;
    private Button btnCreateProduct;
    JSONParser jsonParser  = new JSONParser();
     private static String url_create_product = "**localhost/android_coonect/product.php**";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter into button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "call createNewProduct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

     class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
     {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onPreExecute();
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args0) 
        {
            System.out.println("doInBackground");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "doInBackground", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+url_create_product, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             pDialog.dismiss();
        }
     }
}

 here i am not used web-server but using json and I give information about database
I have made androiddb database and table is products that is given below

CREATE TABLE products(
pid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(100) not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null,
description text,
created_at timestamp default now(),
updated_at timestamp
);
I try to enter data through android activity but error generate so please help..`enter code here`
```

Comment: Plz see this url http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously 'localhost' isn't the correct URL that you want to connect to.

if you're running this app from an emulator and you want to connect to a web server running on the pc running the emulator, use 10.0.2.2, more about this - http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

if you're not on an emulator, use the actual ip/host of the machine running the web server. make sure its accessible to the Android device first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this app on emulator us 10.0.2.2 and if you want to use on real device then use your computer IP address 192.168.X.X