# C# UWP - How to connect Mobile Emulator to a local MySQL Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I'm trying to connect my Emulator app to a MySQL Database i created. It works if i access the database using an app/website from the **LAPTOP**. But it fails to recognize the database if i am accessing it using the **EMULATOR**, my guess it that it treats the Windows Emulator as an external device. I already added Port 3306 (Default MySQL Port) in the firewall exceptions, freed database privileges, and used the IP Address of the Laptop and Emulator, and still, i get the **"Cannot connect to any of the specified MySQL Hosts"**.

**DB Connection Code:**

```
private async void dbConnectAsync()
    {
        string con = "server=192.168.8.100:3306;database=donation;uid=root;password=;SslMode=none;CharSet=utf8";
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(con);
        using (conn = new MySqlConnection(con))
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                var dialog2 = new MessageDialog(err.Message);
                dialog2.Title = "Connection Error";
                dialog2.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Ok", Id = 0 });
                var res = await dialog2.ShowAsync();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection of php and mysql database with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873951/connection-of-php-and-mysql-database-with-android)

Comment: Try using IP 10.0.2.2. Please have a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: I used my host IP (192.168.8.100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using host PC's IP Address which is `192.168.8.100` and removed the `:3306` fixed the issue.